# If $a$, $b$, $c$ are three positive numbers in harmonic sequence, show that $a^2+c^2>2b^2$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, harmonic-numbers, arithmetic-progressions

If $a$, $b$, $c$ are three positive numbers in harmonic sequence, show that $a^2+c^2>2b^2$.

My attempt :
$(a-c)^2>0$

$a^2+c^2>2ac$

This is true for any two real positive values of $a$ and $c$.

Again,

If $a$, $b'$, $c$ are in geometric progression then

$b'^{2} = ac$. So

$a^2+b^2>2b'^{2}$

Comment: $\frac{a}{b}>\frac{b}{c}$, $ac>b^2$.

Comment: remark: you want to impose the condition that the sequence is not constant.

Answer (score 1):

$\implies b=\dfrac{2ca}{c+a}$

$$\left(\dfrac ab\right)^2+\left(\dfrac cb\right)^2=(c+a)^2\left(\dfrac1{4c^2}+\dfrac1{4a^2}\right)$$

Now $(c+a)^2-4ca\ge0\iff(c+a)^2\ge4ca$

and $\dfrac{\dfrac1{4c^2}+\dfrac1{4a^2}}2\ge\dfrac1{4ca}$

Both equality occur if $c=a$

Comment: How did you get $\dfrac {a}{b}=\dfrac {2c}{c+a}$?

Comment: Let $a=1, b=\frac12, c= \frac13$, then $\frac{a}{b}=2$ but $\frac{2c}{a+c}=\frac{\frac23}{\frac43}=\frac12$. We do have $\frac{b}{a}=\frac{2c}{a+c}$ from the first equation.

Comment: @SiongThyeGoh, Thanks

Comment: @blue_eyed_..., Please find the updated answer

Comment: @labbhattacharjee, how is $(c+a)^2-4ca\geq 0$?

Comment: @blue_eyed_..., $(c+a)^2-4ca=(c-a)^2\ge0$ for real $c-a$

Comment: @labbhattacharjee, how do we get $a^2+c^2>2b^2$ from that?

Comment: $$(c+a)^2\ge4ca, \dfrac1{4c^2}+\dfrac1{4a^2}\ge\dfrac2{4ca} $$ Now multiply

Answer (score 1):

A.M.-G.M.-H.M.

$a^2+c^2\ge 2ac=2(\sqrt{ac})^2\ge 2\left(\frac{2}{\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{c}}\right)^2=2b^2$ with equality holds if and only if $a=b=c$.

Comment: Are $a,b,c$ in AP and GP?

Comment: They are in H.P.

Comment: If so, then can we use $AM>GM>HM$??

Comment: $AM\ge GM \ge HM$ holds if the numbers are positive. They are not necessarily in AP, GP ot HP.

Comment: I didn't understand what you did after $a^2+c^2>2ac$?

Comment: It is $a^2+c^2\ge 2ac$, LHS may be equal to RHS.

Comment: By AM-GM inequality, $\frac{a^2+c^2}{2}\ge ac$, with the equality holds if and only if $a=c$.

Comment: so you substitied the value of HM $b$ in place of $(\sqrt {ac})^2$?

Comment: By GM-HM inequlaity, $\sqrt{ac}\ge\frac{2}{\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{c}}$, with the equality holds if and only if $a=c$.

Comment: Oh. I just find that I have typos in the last 2 steps. Please read the edited answer.

Comment: I just have trouble understanding this 
$$2(\sqrt {ac})^2\geq 2(\dfrac {2}{\dfrac {1}{a}+\dfrac {1}{c}})^2$$?

Comment: Maybe you can put it in this way. By AM-GM inequality, $\frac{\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{c}}{2}\ge \sqrt{(\frac{1}{a})(\frac{1}{c})}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{ac}}$. This implies that $\sqrt{ac}\ge \frac{2}{\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{c}}$.

Comment: I mean if $b$ is the GM between $a$ and $b$ then can't we directly substitute $b^2$ in place of $ac$ in this inequality $a^2+c^2>2ac$?

Comment: It is given in the question that $b$ is the HM of $a$ and $c$.